# How to call custom plugin function directly from browser URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress,I am working on wordpress custom plugin, I want to call custom plugin function directly from browser URL, I am trying to access it with this URL  `http://localhost/wordpress-o/wp-admin/admin.php?page=master&action=test` but it is not working, here is my whole plugin code, can anyone please check my code, and help me to resolve this issue ?

```
class WCP_BackEnd_Master_Controller {
    public function index() {
        ob_start();
        global $wpdb;       
        include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/html/list_master_details.php");
        $s = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        print $s;
    }

    public function test() {
        echo "sdsdsd";
        die;
    }

    function add_menu_pages() {
        add_menu_page('Master', 'Master', 'manage_options', 'master', Array("WCP_BackEnd_Master_Controller", "index"));
    }

}
add_action('admin_menu', array("WCP_BackEnd_Master_Controller", 'add_menu_pages'));
add_action('wp_ajax_WCP_BackEnd_Master_Controller::test', Array('WCP_BackEnd_Master_Controller', 'test'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_WCP_BackEnd_Master_Controller::test', array('WCP_BackEnd_Master_Controller', 'test'));
```

Comment: There is no way to run that plugin code directly. It will be called by the Wordpress based on the actions and filters that you set.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found, we can create rest api and use it, here what i did with rest api 
Need to use it with this URL : `http://localhost/wordpress-o/wp-json/my-route/my-phrase`

```
function my_register_route() {
    register_rest_route('my-route', 'my-phrase', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'custom_phrase',
            )
    );
}
function custom_phrase() {
    return rest_ensure_response('Hello World! This is my first REST API');
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'my_register_route');
```